# Call if statement inside update post call

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm almost done with a script that I built, but I have one question.

I have the following function:

```
function clean_post_titles() {
    $office_data = get_offices_array();
    foreach ($office_data as $office) {
        if ($office['brand']) {
            wp_update_post([
                'ID' => $office['post_id'],
                'post_title' => $office['brand'] . ' (' . $office['location'] . ')'
            ]);
        } else {
            wp_update_post([
                'ID' => $office['post_id'],
                'post_title' => $office['office'] . ' (' . $office['location'] . ')'
            ]);
        }
    }
    echo 'All of the office titles have been updated';
}
```

The function works great, but there are instances where `$office['location']` is missing and I get an output as `Office ()` instead of `Office (Location)`.

Is there a way to call an if statement inside the actual `wp_update_post`? Like something along the lines of `'post_title' => $office['brand'] . if ($office['location']) ' (' . $office['location'] . ')'`

**Could I somehow incorporate a ternary operator? - Also, if you think I can clean up the code a bit, please guide me**

If there is brand and no office, just output brand, otherwise combine brand + location with the parentheses.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
foreach ($office_data as $office) {
    $officeBrand = $office['brand'] ? $office['brand'] : $office['office'];
    $location = $office['location'] ? $office['location'] : null;
    $post = [
        'ID' => $office['post_id'],
        'post_title' => $location ? $officeBrand . ' (' . $office['location'] . ')' : $officeBrand,
    ];
    wp_update_post($post);
}
```